# Mongodb: Do I have to update all documents in order to introduce a new field?

Tags: mongodb

I have a scenario where I'm actively building out a web app and while most of the schema was known we introduced a new field and I'm wanting to add it in moving forward. Upon adding this and saving the record via API to MongoDB it doesn't store this new field. I'm curious if I have to add this field to ALL documents in order for MongoDB to allow it to be stored. At this stage I'd prefer to avoid that if possible since I'm in the development phase.

Comment: No. From the database perspective documents can have any fields regardless of what other documents in the same collection have. What do you mean when you say "it doesn't store the new field"? Are you getting an error? How are you attempting to store the field? Are you doing this in the shell or with a driver or?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, per [the documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/data-modeling/):

> Data in MongoDB has a flexible schema. Collections do not enforce document structure by default.

[Here is a playground demonstration](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5PEpkx9hNz9) showing a collection with a mixture of fields present in the documents. It `update`s one of the documents to add a new `num` field that neither of the other two documents have or get.

If you are observing otherwise then something else in your environment (ORM, JSON schema, etc) is configured and interfering with your desired behavior.